# Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, here's my query:

```
SELECT '$'
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR (6), Cast(Avg(TotalPrice) AS NUMERIC (6, 2))) AS 'Average Price',
       '$'
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR (6), Cast(Min(TotalPrice) AS NUMERIC (6, 2))) AS 'Minimum Price',
       '$'
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR (6), Cast(Max(TotalPrice) AS NUMERIC (6, 2))) AS 'Maximum Price'
FROM   Invoice;
```

The AVG column and the MIN column work fine but the MAX column returns:

"Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar"

And I'm not sure why I get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NUMERIC(6,2) indicates total 6 digits and out of which 2 are decimal places.

you have a value like 1234.66 then total characters needed is 7

Get the maximum value and use appropriate varchar size, here you need atleast `varchar(7)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT '$'
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR (10), Cast(Avg(TotalPrice) AS NUMERIC (8, 2))) AS 'Average Price',
       '$'
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR (10), Cast(Min(TotalPrice) AS NUMERIC (8, 2))) AS 'Minimum Price',
       '$'
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR (10), Cast(Max(TotalPrice) AS NUMERIC (8, 2))) AS 'Maximum Price'
FROM   Invoice;
```

Comment: Why does the OP need to change the NUMERIC declaration from (6,2) to (8,2)?

Comment: Beacuse in NUMERIC (6, 2) (precision = 6)
The maximum total number of decimal digits that will be stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point. so precision has to increased.

Comment: There isn't any indication that MAX(TotalPrice) is exceeding NUMERIC(6,2).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that a 'Numeric(6,2)' has up to 6 digits, plus a decimal point (or comma depending on where you are). So you will need to have 'VARCHAR(7)' instead of 6 to cater for this.